# How long will it takes two miscible liquids to fully mix (homogenize) through diffusion?

Tags: solubility, diffusion

This question occurred to me while I was pouring milk into my coffee and was too lazy to stir.

Assume you have some volume $V_a$ of liquid A directly on top of another volume $V_b$ of liquid B. The two liquids are fully miscible. With no stirring, how long until the solution becomes fully homogenous solely by diffusion?

Comment: There's no 'formula' per se, without knowing some more details eg the mass of the liquids, the viscosity of the liquids etc. It's easier for gases, where you can apply [Graham's Diffusion Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_law). For liquids, you should use a stopwatch, conduct the experiment and share the results with us :)

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Haha, I expected it to be a pretty tricky problem. If it helps, you can assume whatever else you like: the masses of the liquids, the temperature, force of gravity (or zero-g), air pressure, diffusion coefficients, etc. Even an answer to a much simpler problem (spherical cow) would be interesting.

Comment: Diffusion is a slow process, see Ficks's Laws of diffusion and look up diffusion coefficients, typically $D=10^{-9}\mathrm{\,m^2\,/s}$ and distance diffused $\ell=\sqrt{6Dt}$ in time $t$. In most cased, as it your example, convection dominates over diffusion